# google search programmatically using php with all result pages

Tags: php, google-api

hi i am trying to do google search using php program.Results are coming but i am getting only four results.
What to do any suggestions..
Here is my code

```
<?php
    $query = 'xyz';
    $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&num=10&q=".$query;

    $body = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($body);
    print_r($json);
    for($x=0;$x<count($json->responseData->results);$x++){

        echo "<b>Result ".($x+1)."</b>";
        echo "<br>URL: ";
        echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->url;
        echo "<br>VisibleURL: ";
        echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->visibleUrl;
        echo "<br>Title: ";
        echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->title;
        echo "<br>Content: ";
        echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->content;
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
?>
```

please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have full control over how many results that can be obtained in the query. But you can control the results size (**`rsz=large`**), and where it starts

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `$apiKey`, `$customSearchEngineKey`? It's a wonder how this is even working for you.